# Why is this partisan subtration game a periodic one?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

How to solve this exercise of Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory"?

> Let $S_L$ and $S_R$ be sets of positive integers. The partisan subtraction game on $S_L$ and $S_R$ is played with a single heap of $n$ tokens. On her move, Left must remove $k$ tokens for some $k\in S_L$; likewise, on his move Right removes $k$ tokens for some $k\in S_R$. Denote by $o(H_n)$ the (normal play) outcome of a heap of $n$ tokens. Prove that the sequence $n \mapsto o(H_n)$ is periodic, i.e., there is some $p>0$ such that $o(H_{n+p})=o(H_n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

An important observation: this exercise is at the beginning of the book, so it is not supposed to use any advanced tool or theorem. I am probably being dumb and missing something obvious. My pride usually forbids me of ever giving up at solving a mathematical problem, but right now I really have to optimize my time, so I am asking for help instead of losing several days at this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know your background, but I want to point out/remind that Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory" is a ([post](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/postgraduate)-)graduate level text and ideally a second text on CGT. This problem is easier with more undergraduate level combinatorics-type experience, and much easier with prior exposure to similar results in a first text on CGT. Not all of them, but there are a fair number of harder problems in Siegel, I feel.

Comment: @MarkS. I suppose that this one really made me look like an undergraduate student or something like this (lol), so I understand your concerns. In fact, I was never good in combinatorial problems, I am more of an analyst than anything else. My main interest here are the surreal numbers, I just want to know the very basics of CGT and (after reading the first chapter of "winning ways") Siegel looked like a nice reference before going for Gonshor (I gave up ONAG after spending several days finishing the details of this proof that On is a field - that book is way too sketchy!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$ be the largest element of $S_L\cup S_R$.  Notice then that for $n\geq m$, $o(H_n)$ is completely determined by the $m$-tuple $$t_n=(o(H_{n-1}),o(H_{n-2}),\dots,o(H_{n-m})),$$ since this tells you the outcome of all possible positions you can reach after one move from a heap of $n$ tokens.  There are only finitely many $m$-tuples of positions, and so eventually they must repeat: there exist $N'>N\geq m$ such that $t_N=t_{N'}$.  This means that $o(H_N)=o(H_{N'})$, but then also $t_{N+1}=t_{N'+1}$ and so $o(H_{N+1})=o(H_{N'+1})$.  It similarly follows by induction that $o(H_{N+k})=o(H_{N'+k})$ for all $k$, or in other words that $o(H_{n+p})=o(H_n)$ for all $n\geq N$ where $p=N'-N$.

Comment: This seems to need a slight adjustment for the fact that it matters whose turn is next. Or if always using one player's move for the position, $m$ is $\max S_L + \max S_R$ instead of $\max(S_L \cup S_R)$. In any case, the basic idea will still work.

Comment: I believe that in this context the term "outcome" refers to the data of both who wins if Left goes first and who wins if Right goes first.

Comment: @aschepler, the outcome here doesn't mean the winner, it means "fuzzy", "zero", "positive" or "negative" (although Siegel uses a different notation).

Comment: @EricWofsey simple and elegant. Well, I've never being good at combinatorial problems, I am clearly better at analysis problems, but still... Now I am feeling bad for not having this idea by myself lol. Well, thanks a lot for solving it for me :)